# PHP 5.4.9 $_POST superglobal not created if 'Content-Type: application/json' is in header

Tags: php, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I noticed a strange bug in my application that happens when using the AWS Elastic Beanstalk PHP 5.4.9 AMI.

When submitting a GET AJAX request that contains the header `'Content-Type: application/json'` the $_POST superglobal is set to null. If I remove that header, it is set as expected to a blank `array()`

Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: Nothing in the docs implies this is expected in PHP > 5.4. I'm not running PHP 5.4.9. However, if you can replicate this by doing the above, I'd submit a bug.

Comment: I remember one question on SO that was talking as well about `$_POST` being `NULL`. I don't know if that was related to AJAX or Json content-type request header. And I dunno if that was resolved anyway. I suggest you setup some test-case and outline here how this can be reproduced. BTW: If you do a GET request, there is no request body, so there is no `Content-Type` request header so it looks a bit bogus to have that at all. Sure this does not explain the `NULL` for `$_POST`, but one probably should not expect too much either.

Comment: Have you got a test case to demonstrate this?  BTW, if you're doing a GET then $_POST shouldn't contain anything (though I believe it should always exist as an empty array)

Comment: My JS framework (spine.js) always contains that header regardless of whether it is GET or POST. My Server side framework (Symfony2) expects  $_POST to always be an array. It's never been a problem until AWS updated php to 5.4.9. I'll do some more testing and report back.

Comment: Create simple page with `<?php var_dump($_POST);`, try `curl -d "[1,2,[3,4]]" -H "Content-type: application/json" http://your.aws/test.php` and see for yourself. If you get an array filled with 1,2 and array(3,4) then you have your answer - no post body will get decoded as null, and post body containg json string will get decoded into php structures inside $_POST.

Comment: What should the $_POST contain? The deserialized JSON data? It shouldn't be array() otherwise, because that is not what was POSTed. This seems to be by design.

Comment: Looks as though PECL HTTP extension was causing the issue.

Comment: Update: Fixed by the PHP team: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63947&edit=2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this was an issue with PECL. When PECL HTTP is installed running PHP 5.4, it causes $_POST to be set to null when a "Content-Type: application/json" header is provided for a GET request. Removing PECL HTTP solves the problem.

Credit to Michael@AWS for the find. Cross thread: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=413836

Edit: Fixed by the PHP team: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63947&edit=2